# SSRS 2008 R2 Parameter dropdown conditional availability

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

In SSRS for SQL Server 2008 R2, is it possible to have a parameter in a drop-down, with multiple values allowed, unless a specific value is selected?

For example, a parameter list could have values A, B, C, D, and E.

The user can select any combination of A, B, or C. But, if the user selects D or E, no other values can be selected. Only D or E can be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting values in the parameter list doesn't trigger an event, so there is no way to dynamically control what other values can be selected. The best solution would be to control the behavior once the View Report button is clicked.

1. Add a message explaining the invalid selection.
2. Add visibility expression to it so that it only displays when applicable.
3. Add the opposite visibility expression condition to a rectangle that holds the remainder of the report.

This way you get a friendly warning message when you try to view the report with invalid combinations.